# Is there a complete admin panel/interface for MQTT net or or any other private MQTT Servers/Broker?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'm making a simple automation system for someone and require a MQTT admin panel for server/broker. I want it such that the admin who runs the server, is able to see and change the password of the server or client. Also the admin would be able to see the all the topics and remove the subscription of of any client if they want. Admin will also be able to see all the messages sent and received.

I was currently looking at C# MQTTnet and Mosquitto but all the servers require manipulation in config files through CLI(there own set of commands on CLI). Isn't there something I can use so that all is done in clean code with WPF form for interface? Is there a solution for this problem? I want a user interface for admin.

Also can a MQTT server run by a novice user? who has no technical knowledge?

I am new so Stack Overflow sent me here to question.

Comment: I think we need to question your goals here. Please [edit](https://iot.stackexchange.com/posts/5049/edit) the question to add what settings you want to dynamically change in the broker config (any why you think you need to change these). Also we need to know more about the solution the broker will be part of as monitoring messages is normally not of any use to an admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is purely user authentication and authorisation administration, then none of this should be done directly by the broker.

The Username/Password information and ACL for topics is all held in an external database (using things like the mosquitto auth_plugin) and how you choose to update that DB is entirely up to you as it will totally depend on what other systems it needs to integrate with (e.g. existing staff/user lists).

Any Administrator would never interrogate the broker for what topics a client is subscribed to (and definitely would not try to edit that list in the broker), but would set up the ACLs for that user to control what topics they are allowed to publish/subscribe to.

And as for monitoring messages, this will very much depend on the volume os messages, but a broker will happily process more messages than it makes sense to try and visualise unfiltered. And the way to do this is just to have a client with the correct ACL entries to be able to see everything.

As for a novice administrating the broker, there should be nothing for them to administrate except the users and what pre-defined ACL groups they should be part of. The ACL grouping should have been determined by the solution architect as part of the design and as I said earlier, this should be integrated into what ever systems already exist.